# IIS Rest Service gives 404 Error from External Server

Tags: web-services, wcf, iis

I have installed a WCF Service which provides REST services. On my development machine it works fine, but I am having a problem with deployment. For security reasons, the actual service is installed on one server which sits behind a firewall. Access to that server is from an external server which provides a front end passing the calls through the firewall and returning the answers to the client. Both servers run IIS 7.
My web.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
  <section name="TalLimoService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
  ...
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
  ...
</appSettings>
<system.web>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.0"/>
  <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,%,&amp;,\,?"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings />
  <client />
  <services>
   <service name="SomethingService.SomethingService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
     <!--Service Endpoints-->
     <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above-->
     <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="TalLimoService.ITalLimoService" behaviorConfiguration="web" />
   </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
    -->
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
<system.diagnostics>
...
</system.diagnostics>
<applicationSettings>
...
</applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

When I browse the service from the internal server, I get appropriate responses.  When I browse from the internet or from the external server, I get a 404 error. The website log file records both attempts, including the 200 code from the internal server and the 404 from the external server.  For example:

```
2014-11-18 ... 192.0.0.1 GET /SomethingService/SomethingService.svc/SomeFunction/Parameter - 80 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+... 200 0 0 124
2014-11-18 ... 192.168.1.6 GET /SomethingService/SomethingService.svc/SomeFunction/Parameter - 80  212.143.135.6 404 0 2 218
```

The trace log defined in the web.config file records the service response from the internal call, but there is no record in the trace log of the call from the external server. Can someone suggest what might be happening? Or offer a clue on how to debug this?

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue to me

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I wasn't looking closely enough at the log. In fact, the calls from the external server looked like this:

```
GET /SomethingService/SomethingService.svcSomeFunction/Parameter - 80  212.143.135.6 404 0 2 218
```

In other words, the slash mark separating the URL from the function template was missing.  Since the URL is read from the configuration file in the external server, all I had to do was add the slash to the config file.  This explains why the call worked from the internal server, where I typed the URL and function name into a browser address bar.

The moral of the story: compare strings very carefully, and if possible do it programatically. Computers are too stupid to miss the difference.